# Dash search function displaying 'old' result

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search

I'm no Ubuntu expert but I have had brief experience with Linux in the past and use it a bit at my university.

Today I had an issue with the Dash search function.

Specifically I downloaded a program called Teamspeak 3 to my **/Downloads** folder.  I then executed the .run file and installed the program, which resulted in a folder appearing in my **/Downloads** folder containing the program and associated files.

I ran the program a few times from that location but thought *there must be a better place to store the files*. I used the **sudo mv** command to the move the folder into **/opt**.  I later realised the program had been running while I did this but it didn't kick up any errors.  This was no problem, but when I searched the term 'Teamspeak' in the Dash it would still show the **/Downloads** folder instead of the **/opt** folder.

So the problem is simply that the Dash search hasn't updated the folder's location. The program runs fine from **/opt** so thats not an issue.

Any assistance would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As Ubuntu Says:

> The Dash allows you to search for applications and files, showing you
>   applications and files that you have used recently. If you have ever
>   worked on a spreadsheet or edited an image and forgot where you saved
>   it, you will surely find this feature of the Dash to be useful.

You need to use the application from the new location for dash to remember it.